# Create array, triggered by a string and stopped by a string

Tags: powershell, text, vbscript, scripting

I want to create automated documentations about tables in a database. The output should be a excel table.

The first two columns should consist out of column names and whether they may contain null values or not. I want to extract the data from the SQL script, that was used to create the tables, since I don't necessarily have access to all the databases.

The queries are formatted as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
column_name1 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT "" NOT NUll
column_name2 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT "" NOT NUll
column_name2 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT "" NOT NUll
)
```

I want to store all the column_names in an array. So what I want the script to do is:

Go through the sql script.
If he finds Create table + Table he is looking for, add lines to the array , starting after the next "(" until he finds a ")". The value in the array should be cut off after the first space.
If the string contains "not null" add a "x" too the second column of the array.

I am a total scripting newbie. I know how to cut strings, and create the necessary loops. But I have no idea, how I select the right strings. I have searched the web, but havent really found the right answers.

I have powershell and vbscript at my disposal

Can you guys help me out?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you include sample begining values, and the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript here, but I would recommend Powershell if that is available.
Use a regular expression like the example to extract the tablename and the data. From there, you can use the data part to split in lines (use the split function on vbNewLine) and extract the data from each line. Process the data add it to an array.

```
testlines = join(array( _
"nonsense", _
"CREATE TABLE tablename", _
"(", _
"column_name1 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT """" NOT NUll", _
"column_name2 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT """" NOT NUll", _
"column_name2 DATATYPE(len) DEFAULT """" NOT NUll", _
")", _
"more nonsense"), vbNewLine)

Set re = new RegExp
re.Global = true
re.Pattern = "CREATE TABLE (.*)[^\(]*\(([\s\S]*)\)"
Set matches = re.Execute(testlines)
Wscript.echo matches(0).submatches(0)   ' returns 'tablename'
Wscript.echo matches(0).submatches(1)   
    ' returns column_name1 ... to ... NOT NUll on the last line
```

I am willing to help you with the last part, but you need to show some effort first. The proof of the pudding is in the eating.